# unsigned 16 bit integers in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, jvm

I would like to use *bitwise* functions (`bit-shift-right`, `bit-and` etc.) in Clojure where the operands are unsigned 16 bit integers.

A 16 bit integer is a decimal number from 0 to 65535, alternatively a binary number from 0000 0000 0000 0000 to 1111 1111 1111 1111.

For example here 123 is a java.lang.Long, so will produce the wrong answer:

```
(bit-not 123)
```

How do I make 123 an unsigned 16 bit integer so that the above produces the correct answer, which is 65412 in decimal?

So 0000 0000 0111 1011 (123) should become 1111 1111 1000 0100 (65412).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
(->> 123
     bit-not
     (bit-and 16rFFFF))
;65412
```

You can shorten it to:

```
(->> 123
     (bit-and-not 16rFFFF))
;65412
```

We're using `long`s as proxies for unsigned `int`s. The JVM has no unsigned `int`s or `long`s, regardless of which language you use.

Comment: I've been double checking with calculator and 65412 is what the answer should be. It is also what 123 is in this reference: http://adventofcode.com/2015/day/7

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Oops - the mask should be `16rFFFF`, not `16rFF00`. Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Java (and Clojure) do not have an unsigned integer type. Clojure mostly provides only 32-bit signed integer bit operations (other than `unsigned-bit-shift-right` which is equivalent to the `>>>` in Java).

Java 8 does have limited support for treating a 16-bit integer as an unsigned integer via new methods on the Integer and Long classes that can do a few unsigned operations (compare, multiply, divide, remainder). See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

There are external libs that provide this functionality in Java as well like https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOU.

Comment: `char` is an unsigned 16-bit value, though any bit wise operation will widen it to an `int`.

Comment: What should I watch out for? In what way are they limited? I think b/c of the twos-compliment representation almost all operations remain the same. It's just a matter of how you "read" the value. For comparisons/division etc you just need to use the equivalent method. I might be missing something though!

Comment: I'm asking b/c it's be very useful for me to have unsigned rollover in an application I'm writing (in Clojure) but I don't wanna shoot myself in the foot with something unexpected down the line :)